# K-Means: why are my results "muddier" than a website performing a similar function?

Tags: python, k-means

I'm trying to extract the top 3 most-prominent colors in an image. I'm no expert on computer vision or image analysis, so I'm relying on the kindness of strangers and borrowed code. I've got the following Python implementation (abridged to remove database storage of results, etc., so it won't be directly runnable)

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import colorsys
(...)
def centroid_histogram(clusters):
    numLabels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(clusters.labels_)) + 1)
    (hist, _) = np.histogram(clusters.labels_, bins = numLabels)

    # normalize the histogram, such that it sums to one
    hist = hist.astype("float")
    hist /= hist.sum()

    # return the histogram
    return hist
(...)
# load the image and convert it to RGB
image = cv2.imread(image)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# break down the image into one long list of pixels
image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))

# perform KMeans clustering
clusters = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
clusters.fit(image)

histogram = centroid_histogram(clusters)

for (percent, color) in zip(histogram, clusters.cluster_centers_):
    r = int(color[0])
    g = int(color[1])
    b = int(color[2])

    h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0)
    h = h * 360.0
```

I've run the same image through this code, and through [an image-processing website](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/eng/get-dominant-colors-result.php), and the results are different. I understand we don't know the exact algorithm or parameters the site is using. I get that. But the site is getting the results I want, and my code is outputting a darker, more muddied palette. Mine is the bars on the right.

[image: palette comparison]

My code also generates the palette with a percentage, which is why the palette blocks are unequal. (Is that the issue?)

Thanks.

Comment: I am just starting to learn image processing, clustering, etc and following links to see how broad the subject is - so I know almost nothing. But I'll hazard a guess to answer the question since there is an obvious experiment to try. You want the top 3 most-prominent colors but I think your k-means clusters=3 request says all my colors fit within ONLY 3 (average, muddy) colors and asks what are they? We could guess that the web site color analyzer you used clustered say 16 colors and showed the 3 most-used ones.